# como hacer un procedimiento almacenado para tabla maestro detalle donde el detalle a su vez tiene otros detalles

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure

Tengo  este procedimiento almacenado para una tabla maestro detalle donde el detalle tenga otros detalles quisiera  saber  cual es la forma  correcta de hacerla. Por que  este procedimiento que  he hecho tiene un error con el @@IDENTITY de la tabla detalle_examen

```
    USE [dbBioclinicos]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[analisis_insertar]    Script Date: 25/02/2021 09:57:44 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[analisis_insertar]
@idusuario int,
@idpaciente int,
@iddoctor int,
@total decimal(11,2),
@detalle type_detalle_v READONLY,
@detallep type_detalle_pruebao READONLY
as
begin
    insert into analisis (idpaciente,idusuario,iddoctor,fecha,total,estado)
    values (@idpaciente,@idusuario,@iddoctor,getdate(),@total,'Aceptado');
    
    insert detalle_examen(idanalisis,idexamen,nomexamen,precio,estado)
    select @@IDENTITY,d.idexamen,d.nombreexamen,d.precio,'Pendiente'
    from @detalle d;
    
    insert detalle_prueba(iddetalle_examen,idprueba,resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,resultado4,valoresdereferencia)
    select de.iddetalle_examen,dt.idprueba,dt.resultado1,dt.resultado2,dt.resultado3,dt.resultado4,dt.valoresReferencia
    from @detallep dt inner  join  detalle_examen de on dt.idexamen=de.idexamen
    where de.iddetalle_examen=@@IDENTITY;
    end
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

Esta  es la interfaz donde  creo la orden de examen ahi se puede ver  que elegí los  exámenes  citometria hematica  y reticulocitos y en el panel aparecen la pruebas  que le corresponden a  cada examen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es un listado  de las personas  con  sus examnes  que eligieron cuando yo le doy doble click a uno de las  celdas  de los  examenes me abrira otro formulario donde  habra cargado las  pruebas  correspondientes  a cada  examen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
por ejemplo aqui al darle  doble click ala  celda de exmen citometria hematica  me carga  todos  sus pruebas

Comment: ¿La tabla analisis tiene algún campo que sea `IDENTITY`?

Comment: Podrías compartir más del código porque veo que estas usando una variable de tipo tabla declarada, para ver en conjunto la instrucción del procedimiento almacenado.

Comment: Cuál es el error que dices que tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Estimado, prueba declarar una variable y asignar el valor del identity a ella, me gustaria saber que tiene @detalle y @detallep pero creo que funcionara.

```
USE [dbBioclinicos]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[analisis_insertar]    Script Date: 25/02/2021 09:57:44 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[analisis_insertar]
@idusuario int,
@idpaciente int,
@iddoctor int,
@total decimal(11,2),
@detalle type_detalle_v READONLY,
@detallep type_detalle_pruebao READONLY
as
begin
DECLARE @id INT

insert into analisis (idpaciente,idusuario,iddoctor,fecha,total,estado)
values (@idpaciente,@idusuario,@iddoctor,getdate(),@total,'Aceptado');

SET @id = (SELECT @@IDENTITY)

insert detalle_examen(idanalisis,idexamen,nomexamen,precio,estado)
select @id,d.idexamen,d.nombreexamen,d.precio,'Pendiente'
from @detalle d;

insert detalle_prueba(iddetalle_examen,idprueba,resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,resultado4,valoresdereferencia)
select de.iddetalle_examen,dt.idprueba,dt.resultado1,dt.resultado2,dt.resultado3,dt.resultado4,dt.valoresReferencia
from @detallep dt inner  join  detalle_examen de on dt.idexamen=de.idexamen
where de.iddetalle_examen=@id;
end
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder. en los datos detalle   y detallep son tipo tabla. En detalle se guardan datos como nombre del examen y precio. Y en detallep se guardan datos como iddetalle-examen, idprueba, resultado

Comment: Bueno te voy a poner un poco en contexto estoy desarrollando un sistema para un laboratorio de análisis clínicos  la tabla  **análisis** es para generar una orden de análisis ahí guardo el idpaciente, idusuario, iddoctor etc. En la tabla **detalle examen** se guardan los exámenes que se le harán al paciente  y sus precios y el estado del examen. Ahora en la tabla **detalle_prueba** se guardan las pruebas que le corresponden a cada examen.

Comment: Mi problema esta en la parte de detalle_prueba cuando quiero agregar varios exámenes y solo se agregan las pruebas  al último examen seleccionado es creo que es debido al @@IDENTITY  que devuelve el último ID en la misma conexión.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar SOCPE_IDENTITY() ya que necesitas encontrar el valor del dato recién insertado dentro del alcance del mismo procedimiento ejecutado, declararía una variable para asignarle el registro recién insertado (eso si en la tabla análisis tienes una columna identity) quita las variables detalle y detallep y mapea dentro del procedimiento los nombres de las tablas, revisa tu diagrama de bd porque veo que puedes normalizar algunos datos, pero en general te podría funcionar esto:

Es necesario que revises que en esas tablas tengas habilitado identity en la llave primaria.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertarAnalisis
@idUsuario int,
@idDoctor int,
@idPaciente int,
@fecha datetime,
@idExamen int,
@precio numeric(18,2),
@observaciones varchar(200),
@metodo varchar(50),
@resultado1 varchar(50),
@resultado2 varchar(50),
@resultado3 varchar(50),
@resultado4 varchar(50),
@idPrueba int
```

AS
BEGIN TRY

DECLARE @idAnalisis int, @idDetalleExamen int, @nomexamen varchar(50), @valorReferencia varchar(50)

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION  TranInsertarAnalisis;
        INSERT INTO analisis(idUsuario, idDoctor, idPaciente, fecha, total, estado)
        VALUES(@idUsuario, @idDoctor, @idPaciente, @fecha, 0.00, 'Aceptado');

        SET @idAnalisis = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

        SET @nomexamen = (SELECT nomexamen FROM examen WHERE idExamen = @idExamen);

        INSERT INTO detalle_examen(idAnalisis, idExamen, nomExamen, precio, observaciones, metodo, estado)
        VALUES(@idAnalisis, @idExamen, @nomexamen, @precio, @observaciones, @metodo, 'Pendiente');

        SET @idDetalleExamen = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());
    
        SET @valorReferencia = (SELECT valorReferencia FROM detalle_examen WHERE idDetalleExamen = @idDetalleExamen);

        INSERT INTO detalle_prueba(idDetalleExamen, idPrueba, resultado1, resultado2, resultado3, resultado4, valoresReferencia)
        VALUES(@idDetalleExamen, @idPrueba, @resultado1, @resultado2, @resultado3, @resultado4, @valorReferencia);
    COMMIT TRANSACTION TranInsertarAnalisis
    
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF(@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  TranInsertarAnalisis;
            PRINT 'Error detectado, se deshicieron los cambios en la base de datos';
        END
    SELECT
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
        ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
        ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
        ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH
```

Comment: en los datos detalle   y detallep son tipo tabla. En detalle se guardan datos como nombre del examen y precio. Y en detallep se guardan datos como iddetalle-examen, idprueba, resultado

Comment: Bueno te voy a poner un poco en contexto estoy desarrollando un sistema para un laboratorio de análisis clínicos  la tabla  **análisis** es para generar una orden de análisis ahí guardo el idpaciente, idusuario, iddoctor etc. En la tabla **detalle examen** se guardan los exámenes que se le harán al paciente  y sus precios y el estado del examen. Ahora en la tabla **detalle_prueba** se guardan las pruebas que le corresponden a cada examen

Comment: . Mi problema esta en la parte de detalle_prueba cuando quiero agregar varios exámenes y solo se agregan las pruebas  al último examen seleccionado es creo que es debido al @@IDENTITY  que devuelve el último ID en la misma conexión.

Comment: Hola es más seguro usar Scope_identity() porque tiene alcance solo sobre el batch que ejecutas, esto debido a que lo necesitas dentro del procedimiento te será muy útil.

Comment: hola jorge cuando  ya intente Scope_identity() y no me guarda las pruebas correctas  en cada examen

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu código la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: si ya lo agregue

Comment: Quita las variables detalle y detallep, las llaves primarias en las tablas tienen habilitado el identity insert on?,utiliza los nombres de las tablas para hacer los inserts, te recomiendo que el campo total lo guardes por defecto a cero y que este se vaya actualizando en el momento que se asigne el precio al detalle de exámen, evalúa que campos necesitas porque veo que estas guardando el valor del análisis y el valor de detalle examen y la relación es de uno a muchos, entonces como actualizaras al momento de tener dos detalles de exámenes asociados a un análisis? Actualizaré mi respuesta...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120179/discussion-between-mario-and-jorge-torselli).

Comment: Jorge no tengo habilitado el identity insert on

Comment: puedes volver a ver mi pregunta ya actualize la pregunta expliacando un poco masa detalle

Comment: Mario revisa mi respuesta la actualice

Comment: si voy a  ver  que tal

Comment: no funciono, he intentado insertalo manualmente  con el  SCOPE_IDENTITY() Y NADA

Comment: sabe existe alguna otra  forma de  capturar los  valores identity aparte de @@identity, IDENT_CURRENT ,SCOPE_IDENTITY()